# How to avoid a lot of requests to db for unlikely to change data, while keeping the service stateless?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rabbitmq

I'm getting messages in a message queue (rabbitmq), and I need to filter the messages by some data in my database (mongodb). 
The options are:

1. Read the information from the db every time I consume a message (the information in the db is unlikely to change in that time, and it can be about 1000 requests per second).
2. Store a variable in the nodejs server to keep the value coming from the db and get the value from the db in an interval, but that means a stateful application.
3. Maybe you know some better solution, keeping the service stateless without not needed requests to the database (or you think I shouldn't mind that amount of requests).

What should I do? I don't want to use an external cache like redis either.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are not being changed often, then you could add an indexer for that field. Indexing a field will store the data in memory, so the recall time and impact are fall smaller than on non-indexed fields. However, when one of these fields is updated, mongo must go back through and update the index for everything with that field in that collection.

[Here's some more information on indexes.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

Edit: I meant to also mention that you shouldn't have more than 15-20 indexes on any one collection. More than that will kill the performance of the server. Use sparingly!